# Using 'they' instead of 'it' in RSpec

Tags: rspec, rspec3

I have a set of examples that more accurately refer to a set of objects, instead of a singular object.  "they 'should do/be x'" makes more sense, for example:

```
describe ArrayElements do
  they 'are ordered' do
    ...
  end

  they { should all_be_identical }
end
```

Is it possible to configure RSpec 3 to accept they?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure aliases for `it` by using `alias_example_to`  when you configure rspec (for example in your spec_helper.rb):

```
Rspec.configure do |config|
  config.alias_example_to :they
end
```

You can also use this to set metadata on all examples created in this way, for example

```
Rspec.configure do |config|
  config.alias_example_to :they, :type => :collection
end
```

You can also create aliases for context/describe too, with `alias_example_group_to`